# Occupy height of a div when content is rotated

Tags: css

I tried rotating the content of my fixed div and it rotates as expected but the problem is it doesn't occupy the height of the div.

Sample fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sLh5rb7c/).

HTML:

```
<div class="outer-left">
  <h2 class="paginator">Page 1 0f 10</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer-left {
    background: #EFB041;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    width: 4%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 18%;
}

.paginator {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    color: #fff;
}
```

> Note: I can make it by applying width = auto on the div but how can I
>   achieve it using a fixed width?

Now I can achieve it adding

```
margin-top: 600px;
white-space:nowrap;
```

inside the paginator class. but is there a way cleaner on how to get this done?

Comment: OT: you don't need `-moz-` and `-o-` vendor prefixes except if you're supporting Fx 15 and Opera 11.5 (chances are you aren't). And `-ms-` is for IE9. Source [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform). Long live Autoprefixer :)

Comment: @FelipeAls, I actually use those prefixes for supporting old browsers.

Comment: @claudios are you sure that your site has users with these browsers? Check out the statistics on [CanIUse?](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform), it seems like the global usage of these browsers is about `0.01%`.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov, yes coz base on the stats we got from our system. This site is serving campaigns and surveys btw

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/KerryRuddock/sLh5rb7c/88/)

Maybe this jsfiddle works for you.

```
HTML:
    <div class="outer-left">
      <h2 class="paginator">Page&nbsp;1&nbsp;of&nbsp;10</h2>
    </div>
>
CSS:

  .outer-left {
    position: relative;
    background: #EFB041;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 5%;
    left: 18%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;

}

.paginator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: -2.0em;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0;

  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  color: #fff;
}
```